# How to set a progress element to indeterminate

Tags: javascript, html, progress-bar

How can I set a [progress](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/progress) element to indeterminate after setting a value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [your documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/progress):

> If there is no `value=""` attribute, the progress bar is *indeterminate*; this indicates that an activity is ongoing with no indication of how long it is expected to take.

And still according to the documentation:

> To change the progress bar to indeterminate after giving it a value you must remove the `value` attribute with `element.removeAttribute("value")`

Comment: It seems weird that they would add an indeterminate property to [checkboxes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/checkbox) but not to progress bars.

Comment: `el.removeAttribute("value")` will change the progress bar to indeterminate without having to recreate it.